# add some UITextView s and other elements in UIScrollView programmatically Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, uitextview

As I'm beginner in Xamarin IOS, I need your answer or suggestion for adding some elements in UIScrollView.

I've a ViewController which contains one UIImageView then some UILabel and two or more UITextView. As the texts are long, I've to add a UIScrollView for scrolling the ViewController. So, I've written this code:

```
public class PostViewController : UIViewController
    {
        UIScrollView scrollView;

        private UIImageView _postHeaderImage;

        private UILabel _postTopTag;
        private UILabel _postTitle;

        private UILabel _sourceAndpublicationDate;

        private UITextView _postSummary;
        private UITextView _postText;

        private UIImage image;

        public PostViewController()
        {
            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();



            // ScrollView
            scrollView = new UIScrollView();

            image = UIImage.FromFile("Article1.jpg");
            _postHeaderImage = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("Article1.jpg"));


            _postTopTag = InitUILabel("Santé", fontSize: 12, color: Colors.TextGrayColor, alignment: UITextAlignment.Left, bold: true);
            _postTopTag.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString("Santé", underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.Single);

            _postTitle = InitUILabel("Alaska - Une «éponge miracle» contre le cancer ", fontSize: 26, bold: true, alignment: UITextAlignment.Left);


            _sourceAndpublicationDate = InitUILabel("www.letelegramme.fr" + " - " + "Depuis 23 Heure(s)", fontSize: 13, alignment: UITextAlignment.Left);

            _postSummary = new UITextView();
            _postSummary.Editable = false;
            _postSummary.ScrollEnabled = false;
            _postSummary.Text = "La « Latrunculia austini » vit à une profondeur variant de 70 à 220 m, dans des zones difficiles d'accès.";



            image = UIImage.FromFile("Article1.jpg");
            _postHeaderImage = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("Article1.jpg"));


            _postText = new UITextView();
            _postText.Editable = false;
            _postText.ScrollEnabled = false;
            _postText.Text = @"«La molécule la plus active contre le cancer du pancréas».
Des chercheurs ont découvert, en Alaska (États-Unis), qu'une petite éponge des profondeurs possède une composition chimique capable de traiter cette tumeur parmi les plus agressives.
Une petite éponge verte, découverte dans les eaux glacées et sombres au large de l'Alaska, pourrait offrir la première arme efficace contre le cancer du pancréas, une tumeur agressive face à laquelle la médecine a peu de recours.

« Personne ne regarde cette éponge en se disant c'est une éponge miracle, mais elle pourrait l'être », s'exclame Bob Stone, chercheur au Centre scientifique de la pêche d'Alaska de l'Agence américaine océanique et atmosphérique (NOAA). Il a été le premier à découvrir cette éponge de la taille d'une balle de golfe, baptisée « Latrunculia austini », en 2005, lors d'une expédition d'exploration des écosystèmes sous-marins.

Des tests en laboratoire ont révélé que plusieurs de ses molécules détruisent sélectivement les cellules cancéreuses pancréatiques, a indiqué Mark Hamann, un chercheur de la faculté de médecine de l'Université de Caroline du Sud, en collaboration avec Fred Valeriote, de l'Institut Henry Ford du cancer, à Detroit. « C'est sans aucun doute la molécule la plus active contre le cancer du pancréas que nous voyons », se réjouit Mark Hamman.";

            scrollView.AddSubviews(_postHeaderImage, _postTopTag, _postTitle, _sourceAndpublicationDate, _postSummary, _postText);

            View.AddSubview(scrollView);
        }

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            var frameWidth = View.Frame.Width ;

            scrollView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, this.View.Bounds.Size.Width, 5000);
            scrollView.ContentSize = scrollView.Frame.Size; // This may not be what you actually want, but what you had before was certainly wrong.

            _postHeaderImage.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, (View.Frame.Width * image.Size.Height / image.Size.Width));

            float width = (float)(View.Frame.Size.Width - 40);




            _postTopTag.Frame = new CGRect(10, _postHeaderImage.Frame.Size.Height, frameWidth, 20);

            _postTitle.Frame = new CGRect(10, _postTopTag.Frame.Y + _postTopTag.Frame.Size.Height, frameWidth, 80);

            _sourceAndpublicationDate.Frame = new CGRect(10,_postTitle.Frame.Y + _postTitle.Frame.Size.Height, frameWidth, 20);


            SizeF size = (SizeF)((NSString)_postSummary.Text).StringSize(_postSummary.Font, constrainedToSize: new SizeF(width, (float)View.Frame.Size.Height),
                    lineBreakMode: UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
            _postSummary.Frame = new CGRect(10, _sourceAndpublicationDate.Frame.Y + _sourceAndpublicationDate.Frame.Size.Height, size.Width, size.Height);


            size = (SizeF)((NSString)_postText.Text).StringSize(_postText.Font, constrainedToSize: new SizeF(width, (float)View.Frame.Size.Height),
                    lineBreakMode: UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);

            _postText.Frame = new CGRect(10, _postSummary.Frame.Y + _postSummary.Frame.Size.Height, size.Width, size.Height);


        }


        public static UILabel InitUILabel(string text, int? color = null, UITextAlignment? alignment = null, nfloat? fontSize = null, bool? bold = false)
        {
            UILabel _label = new UILabel();
            _label.Text = text;
            _label.TextColor = Colors.FromHex(color == null ? Colors.MainColor : color.Value);
            _label.TextAlignment = (alignment == null ? UITextAlignment.Center : alignment.Value);
            _label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            _label.Lines = 0;
            if (fontSize != null && !bold.Value)
                _label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(fontSize.Value);
            else if (fontSize != null && bold.Value)
                _label.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(fontSize.Value);
            else if (bold.Value)
                _label.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(14f);

            return _label;

        }

    }
```

If you run this controller, you will see that I have lots of problem with size of UIScrollView and also with size of my UITextView s.

In your mind, I am used a good method for displaying my controller or you have another way to propose me ?

*I use IOS 10 in simulator

Thanks

EDIT:

I've used Cirrious but it doesn't worked! 
Here is the code:

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews ();
            View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints ();

            View.AddConstraints (

                scrollView.AtTopOf (View, 50),
                scrollView.WithSameWidth (View)
            );

            scrollView.AddConstraints (
                _postTopTag.Below (_postHeaderImage, 15),
                _postTopTag.AtLeftOf (View, 10),
                _postTopTag.WithSameWidth (View).Minus (40)
                //...
            );
        }
```

Comment: Setting frames directly is not the best practice approach. You should create autolayout constraints

Comment: I've used Cirrious.FluentLayouts.Touch but it didn't display my elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the explaination, I think you need to understand the difference between `Frame` and  `ConentSize` on UIScrollview.

- Frame : The area you want to display on the screen.
- ContentSize: The area which can scroll to see.

### Solution on `Frame` and `AutoLayout`

- #### Frame

  Set frame at first.

  ```
  scrollView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, this.View.Bounds.Size.Width, this.View.Bounds.Size.Height);
  ```

  Set contentSize after setting all the control(calcuate height according to the last control )

  ```
  _postText.Frame = new CGRect(10, _postSummary.Frame.Y + _postSummary.Frame.Size.Height, size.Width, size.Height);
  //insert here ,at the end of method ViewDidLayoutSubviews
  scrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(View.Frame.Width, _postText.Frame.Y + _postText.Frame.Height);
  ```
- #### AutoLayout

  It is complex in the way.

  About how to autolayout on UIScrollview , refer to my recent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642679/xamarin-ios-autolayout-resize-width-and-vertical-scroll-automatically-for-vario/46664304#46664304) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488824/xamarin-ios-auto-layout-within-scroll-view/46539635#46539635)

  Official API : [Programmatic Layout Constraints](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/programmatic-layout-constraints/)

  Simple Way with AutoLayout : [Cirrious.FluentLayout](https://github.com/FluentLayout/Cirrious.FluentLayout)

  [Autolayouts in UIScrollView using Cirrious.FluentLayouts.Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377407/autolayouts-in-uiscrollview-using-cirrious-fluentlayouts-touch)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
That was exactly what I want. As I told, I'm beginner and appreciate for your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using AutoLayout constraints as the best approach but if you do this using code behind, that can be also feasible by setting proper height and width of scrollview along with setting ContentSize properly.

Height and Width of scrollview should be same as it's parent view in your case.

ContentSize should be according to your actual content inside the scrollview.
Ex. ContentSize height parameter needs to be set as total height of your inner content of scrollview.

ContentSize width parameter will be same as scrollview width.

Also make sure you set scrollview's bounce verticall property to true.

In your code it seems that you have set Scrollview size and ContentSize in a wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Cole Xia said the same answer but much more completely.