# How to make UIScrollView scrollable?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview

I'm using a `UIScrollView` to display a few fields, but the `View` does't scroll down,
what am I doing wrong?

```
ScrollView
    |
    View
       | 
       Fields
```

[image]

Comment: ScrollView will scroll if its content size is greater then its frame

Comment: The constraints should be set correctly on view and Fields, Here is [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46804711/8187800).