# Adding UIWebView inside UIScrollView XAMARIN.IOS C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I'd like to add a UIWebView (and some other elements) in a UIScrollView.

First of all, my UIWebView has not a fix text and could be change.

So, as I saw in examples and tutorials I can do it like this:

```
public class testArticleViewController : UIViewController
    {
        private UIScrollView _scrollView;

        //Post elements
        UIWebView _artcileTextWeb;

        public testArticleViewController()
        {
            Title = "test";
            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;


        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {

            string text = @"L'un des deux meilleurs du monde, Lionel Messi, va-t-il manquer la Coupe du monde&nbsp;? L'Argentine se retrouve dans une situation extr&ecirc;mement d&eacute;licate dans la course &agrave; la qualification au Mondial 2018 en faisant match nul (0-0) jeudi face au P&eacute;rou.<br />
<div>
<div>
<div>
<article>
<div>
<div>
<p ><br />Le risque de voir une Coupe du Monde en Russie sans Lionel Messi est bien r&eacute;el&nbsp;: sixi&egrave;me et en dehors de la zone de qualification &agrave; une journ&eacute;e de la fin, l'Albiceleste doit imp&eacute;rativement s'imposer mardi face &agrave; l'&Eacute;quateur, d&eacute;j&agrave; &eacute;limin&eacute;.<br /><br />Cinq &eacute;quipes se tiennent en deux points, entre le Chili (3e, 26 points) et le Paraguay (7e, 24 points) qui garde un mince espoir de qualification gr&acirc;ce &agrave; son succ&egrave;s de jeudi (2-1) face &agrave; la Colombie (4e, 26 points).<br /><br />L'Argentine ne pointe qu'en sixi&egrave;me position, avec le m&ecirc;me nombre de points que les P&eacute;ruviens (5e, 25), qui occupent pour le moment une place de barragiste et r&ecirc;vent &agrave; une premi&egrave;re participation au Mondial depuis 1982.</p>
<h3>Sampaoli est &laquo;tr&egrave;s confiant&raquo;</h3>
<p>M&ecirc;me s'il admet que la position de l'Argentine <em>&laquo;n'est pas tr&egrave;s confortable&raquo;</em>, le s&eacute;lectionneur Jorge Sampaoli se veut <em>&laquo;tr&egrave;s confiant dans le fait que nous allons &ecirc;tre au Mondial&raquo;</em>. Pour le match crucial de jeudi face au P&eacute;rou, la F&eacute;d&eacute;ration argentine avait mis&eacute; sur l'ambiance bouillante du mythique stade de la Bombonera.<br /><br />Pouss&eacute;s par quelque 50 000 supporters, les locaux ont eu beaucoup de mal &agrave; trouver des espaces face &agrave; des P&eacute;ruviens bien regroup&eacute;s derri&egrave;re. Messi a cru ouvrir le score d&egrave;s la 13e minute, sur une belle combinaison sur corner, mais un d&eacute;fenseur s'est jet&eacute; in extremis pour d&eacute;vier un ballon qui semblait prendre la direction des filets. La Bombonera a soupir&eacute; une nouvelle fois dix minutes plus tard, quand Di Maria - remplac&eacute; &agrave; la pause - a manqu&eacute; une belle occasion en tirant au-dessus.<br /><br />Les nerfs &agrave; vif, les supporters ont retenu leur souffle &agrave; la 33e, en voyant Farfan manquer le cadre de peu sur un centre &agrave; ras de terre Trauco. Messi bien touch&eacute; le poteau au retour des vestiaires, mais l'Albiceleste a livr&eacute; une nouvelle fois une copie bien p&acirc;le. <em>&laquo;On ne peut pas en demander plus &agrave; Leo Messi. Il a eu des opportunit&eacute;s, les a cr&eacute;&eacute;es, a eu des balles de but. On a eu un Messi tr&egrave;s intense, celui dont l'Argentine a besoin&raquo;</em>, a consid&eacute;r&eacute; Sampaoli.<br /><br />La derni&egrave;re fois que l'Albiceleste a rat&eacute; un Mondial (celui de 1970, au Mexique), elle avait &eacute;t&eacute; condamn&eacute;e par un match nul (2-2) face au P&eacute;rou, dans ce m&ecirc;me stade de la Bombonera. Cette fois, il reste encore un match, un seul, pour tout changer.</p>
</div>
</div>
</article>
</div>
</div>
</div>";



            var padding = 10;

            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            _scrollView = new UIScrollView()
            { ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false, AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight };

            //Text article
            _artcileTextWeb = new UIWebView();
            _artcileTextWeb.LoadHtmlString(text, null);
            _artcileTextWeb.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;


            var view1 = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue };
            var view3 = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green };


            Add(_scrollView);

            View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

            View.AddConstraints(
                _scrollView.AtLeftOf(View),
                _scrollView.AtTopOf(View),
                _scrollView.WithSameWidth(View),
                _scrollView.WithSameHeight(View));

            _scrollView.Add(view1);
            _scrollView.Add(_artcileTextWeb);
            _scrollView.Add(view3);




            _scrollView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

            var basicwidth = (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 3 * padding) / 2;
            var basicheight = basicwidth / 2;

            _scrollView.AddConstraints(
                view1.AtTopOf(_scrollView, UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height),
                view1.AtLeftOf(_scrollView, padding),
                view1.Width().EqualTo(basicwidth),
                view1.Height().EqualTo(basicheight),

                view3.WithSameTop(view1),
                view3.Left().EqualTo().RightOf(view1).Plus(padding),
                view3.WithSameHeight(view1),
                view3.WithSameWidth(view1),

                _artcileTextWeb.Below(view1, padding),
                _artcileTextWeb.WithSameLeft(view1),
                _artcileTextWeb.WithSameRight(view3),
                _artcileTextWeb.WithSameHeight(_scrollView)

            );
        }



    }
```

If you run it, you will see that the UIScrollView has the same height of screen and it's not dynamic!

So, maybe it seems that the UIWebView has not a correct height (has not a corrected frame size)! If it's the case, how can I predict the Height of UIWebView?

Even if I use CGRect for creating adding UIWebView's frame to my UIScrollView, I need a Height for it!

Do you have any idea dear developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: [Autolayouts in UIScrollView using Cirrious.FluentLayouts.Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377407/autolayouts-in-uiscrollview-using-cirrious-fluentlayouts-touch)

### The correct solution:

Set the `contentSize` of `UIWebView` , and then  let it `AtBottomOf Scrollview`.

#### Round 1

```
_artcileTextWeb.Below(view1, padding),
_artcileTextWeb.WithSameLeft(view1),
_artcileTextWeb.WithSameRight(view3),
_artcileTextWeb.Height().EqualTo(_artcileTextWeb.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height),
_artcileTextWeb.AtBottomOf(_scrollView)
```

But it didn't work , `ScrollView.ContentSize.Height` returns the incorrect result.

#### Round 2

```
_artcileTextWeb = new UIWebView(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
_artcileTextWeb.LoadHtmlString(text, null);
_artcileTextWeb.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;
string result = _artcileTextWeb.EvaluateJavascript("document.body.offsetHeight;");
int height = Convert.ToInt32(result); 


_scrollView.AddConstraints(
            //xxxx

            _artcileTextWeb.Below(view1, padding),
            _artcileTextWeb.WithSameLeft(view1),
            _artcileTextWeb.WithSameRight(view3),
            _artcileTextWeb.Height().EqualTo(height),
            _artcileTextWeb.AtBottomOf(_scrollView)

        );
```

The result always returns 667 (the screen height), so I move calculation to the  method `LoadingFinished` ,set the content height after webview has finished loading.

#### Round 3

New a subclass of UIWebViewDelegate

```
class MyDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
{
    UIScrollView mainView;
    public MyDelegate(UIScrollView view) {
        mainView = view;
    }

    public override void LoadingFinished(UIWebView webView)
    {
        string result = webView.EvaluateJavascript("document.body.offsetHeight;");
        mainView.AddConstraints(webView.Height().EqualTo(Convert.ToInt64(result)));
    }
}
```

In ViewController

```
_artcileTextWeb = new UIWebView(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
_artcileTextWeb.Delegate = new MyDelegate(_scrollView);
_artcileTextWeb.LoadHtmlString(text, null);
_artcileTextWeb.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;

 _artcileTextWeb.Below(view1, padding),
 _artcileTextWeb.AtLeftOf(_scrollView),    //modify this line
 _artcileTextWeb.WithSameWidth(_scrollView), //modify this line
 _artcileTextWeb.AtBottomOf(_scrollView)
```

At last, it works.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed reponse, but I have still problem! I have tested with another text and it works like a charm, but in first text, it lacks a little space for text. here is the code with your instruction : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6zUHkhGxCoNTGhPeHE5SkFrdm8/view?usp=sharing

does it related to Bold part of html ? result in first text is 1156 but I don't n-know why it doesn't work ?

Comment: @alirezartbd After my researching, I found the height calculation is according to the screen width , it always return the same value even if I change the width of webview. So I think we have to set the left and right margin between scrollview to 0. Check my update

Comment: @alirezartbd It seems that still shows incomplete view but it is better than before...

Comment: Yeah, exactly, just I've added 10p to result value and it works perfectly 
Thanks for another time @ColeXia , God Of Xamarin.IOS ;) 

A little question, do you have/know any sources for learning all these details of xamarin.ios ? I'm alireza.rtbd at gmail

Comment: I think  Xamarin official documentation offers detailed explaination and stackoverflow can solved almost your problems，and also Apple Doc is very helpful，All of my knowledge on iOS comes from them ,at last，Happy Coding!