# UITableView doesn't display at all

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I see no reason why my TableView won't display, but it doesn't.  The `GetCell` method in the UITableViewSource never gets called, so obviously that is part of the problem, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why.  I thought it may be because the view is set off the screen, but no matter what I do with the frame. nothing ever appears.  I followed the post [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/populating-a-table-with-data) when constructing the table view, so I believe I got it right, but obviously I'm missing something and nothing I've read online has shed any light on the issue.  My code:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var height = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;
        var width = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Width;
        UIImageView banner = new UIImageView();
        banner.Image = UIImage.FromResource(null, "MYTEST_APP.Resources.drawable.Banner2.jpg");
        banner.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)width, 73);
        banner.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
        UILabel lblTitle = new UILabel();
        lblTitle.Text = theSelectedTeam + " " + "Chat Room";
        UITableView tblMessages = new UITableView();
        tblMessages.Frame = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, (float)width, 400f);
        tblMessages.Source = new MessageSource(GetMessages()); // Returns a List<string> of previous messages, currently there are 9 message strings that are retreived, so there is data
        UITextField txtSendingTextMessage = new UITextField(new CGRect(0, width, width, 100));
        txtSendingTextMessage.Placeholder = "Enter Message To Send Here";

        UIButton btnSendText = new UIButton();
        CGRect ScreenBounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        float buttonWidth = (float)ScreenBounds.Width / 4;
        btnSendText.Frame = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, buttonWidth, 50f);
        btnSendText.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
        btnSendText.SetTitle("Send Text", UIControlState.Normal);
        btnSendText.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(255, 215, 0);

        View.Add(banner);
        View.Add(lblTitle);
        View.Add(tblMessages);
        View.Add(txtSendingTextMessage);
        View.Add(btnSendText);

        View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

        View.AddConstraints(
            banner.AtTopOf(View, 100),
            banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
            banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),
            lblTitle.Below(banner, 5),
            lblTitle.WithSameCenterX(banner),
            tblMessages.Below(lblTitle, 10),
            tblMessages.WithSameCenterX(lblTitle),
            txtSendingTextMessage.Below(tblMessages, 10),
            txtSendingTextMessage.WithSameCenterX(tblMessages),
            btnSendText.Below(txtSendingTextMessage, 10),
            btnSendText.WithSameCenterX(txtSendingTextMessage)
        );


        tblMessages.ReloadData(); // just is case
    }
```

The TableViewSource Code:

```
public class MessageSource : UITableViewSource
{

    List<string> TableItems;
    string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public MessageSource(List<string> items)
    {
        TableItems = items;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return TableItems.Count;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

        //if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier);
        }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess no one has an answer. :( ... I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: You mentioned in another post that use the Cirrious FluentLayout which might be the reason.

Comment: Yes, but t it wasn't that there or here.

Comment: @liqun Shen -Well, to a certian extent you were correct, I was just missing one line of code.  See my answer for the fix. :)

Comment: Excellent work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that when one uses `Cirrious.FluentLayouts` like I do and then executes             `View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();` the tableview gets sized to zero, consequently its not visible.  I simplified my code as such:

```
    public override async void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var height = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
        var width = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width; 
        UIImageView banner = new UIImageView();
        banner.Image = UIImage.FromResource(null, "MY_TESTAPP.Resources.drawable.Banner2.jpg");
        banner.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)width, 73);
        banner.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
        UILabel lblTitle = new UILabel();
        lblTitle.Text = theSelectedTeam + " " + "Chat Room";
        MyMessages = GetMessages();
        tblMessages.LayoutIfNeeded();
        source.Data = MyMessages;
        tblMessages.Source = source;

        UITextField txtSendingTextMessage = new UITextField(new CGRect(0, width, width, 100));
        txtSendingTextMessage.Placeholder = "Enter Message To Send Here";

        UIButton btnSendText = new UIButton();
        CGRect ScreenBounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        float buttonWidth = (float)ScreenBounds.Width / 4;
        btnSendText.Frame = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, buttonWidth, 50f);
        btnSendText.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
        btnSendText.SetTitle("Send Text", UIControlState.Normal);
        btnSendText.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(255, 215, 0);

        View.Add(banner);
        View.Add(lblTitle);
        View.Add(tblMessages);
        View.Add(txtSendingTextMessage);
        View.Add(btnSendText);

        View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

        View.AddConstraints(
            banner.AtTopOf(View, 50),
            banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
            banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),
            lblTitle.Below(banner, 5),
            lblTitle.WithSameCenterX(banner),
            tblMessages.Below(lblTitle, 10),
            tblMessages.AtLeftOf(View),
            tblMessages.WithSameWidth(View),
            tblMessages.Height().EqualTo(height/2),
            txtSendingTextMessage.Below(tblMessages, 10),
            txtSendingTextMessage.WithSameCenterX(tblMessages),
            btnSendText.Below(txtSendingTextMessage, 10),
            btnSendText.WithSameCenterX(txtSendingTextMessage)
        );
    }
```

The line of code that made all the difference is `tblMessages.Height().EqualTo(height/2)`.  And of course there's no documentation anywhere that lets one know, not even in the `Cirrious.FluentLayouts` documentation.  Sigh, so frustrating.  In any event, the post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377407/autolayouts-in-uiscrollview-using-cirrious-fluentlayouts-touch) set me on the correct path.